# Range of successes for multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, hypergeometric-distribution

I'm trying to calculate the probability of drawing specific cards in a deck.  I know that I can use multivariate hypergeometric distribution to calculate for a defined success.  I'm wondering how I can do the same for a range of acceptable successes.

For example (if *k* is the number of successes):

- Drawing less than *k* cards
- Drawing up to *k* cards
- Drawing between *k* and *l* cards (also inclusive of *k* and/or *l*)
- Drawing *k* or more cards
- Drawing more than *k* cards

I'd just like to know if there's a formula for this already, or what the process would be to find these values.

#### Edits after receiving further questions

Let's say we're using a standard 52 card deck of playing cards and they're shuffled.  You're drawing cards off the top of the deck.  Some questions that might be asked are:

- What's the chance of drawing 2 or 3 queens in 5 cards?
- What's the chance of drawing $\le$ 3 queens AND $\ge$ 2 kings in 7 cards?

Because the number of cards is known, the last example translates to 0-3 queens and 2-4 kings.

Comment: You need to tell us more clearly what "drawing $k$ cards" means.  It is not evident what event that refers to.  How many cards are being drawn?  What exactly does $k$ count?  For instance, in a game of standard Poker, the chance that you will be dealt ("draw") $5$ cards is 100% and the chance of being dealt $6$ or more cards is zero.

Comment: @whuber Apologies, updated above.  I was using k as the number of successes.  So it reads (for example): Chance of drawing less than 3 successful outcomes.

Comment: Something is still missing.  How many cards are drawn, how is that number determined, by what process are they drawn (presumably randomly and without replacement, but it would be nice to be explicit about this), and what constitutes a "successful outcome"?

Comment: @whuber Further edits, is that helpful?

Comment: Would it work to run the calculation for each combination (1 queen, 2 kings, 1 queen, 3 kings, ... , 3 queens, 4 kings) and then sum the results?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.  It may be the best approach for problems with small decks like this one.

Comment: Because you have restated so much more clearly and generally in a new thread, I have closed this as a duplicate (which leaves a link to the new thread for future readers).